# Gradle installing/using a plugin jar locally

Tags: java, maven, gradle

In my project I have a proprietary jar that has to be accessed locally. I have tried to find out different ways to install the jar in local maven repository following the official guide.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

But it is not working.

I have made a build.gradle file as follows,

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId = 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz'
                artifactId = 'XYZ'
                version = 'X.X.X'

                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the project settings.gradle.kts the jar is fetched by,

```
plugins {
    id("com.xxx.yyy.zzz.XYZ") version "X.X.X"
}
```

Now, in maven I used to install jars to local repository by mentioning the jar name.

As I am new to gradle possibly I missing some vital understanding.

After executing the command `gradle publishToMavenLocal` I am getting the error,

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/xxx/yyy/zzz/build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'zzz'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: PublishingPlugin.Rules#publishing(ExtensionContainer)
   > Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

If I remove the line `from components.java` the build becomes successful but the jar location is not found and when I execute main project build it says,

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz.XYZ', version: 'X.Y.Z'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.xxx.yyy.zzz.XYZ:X.Y.Z')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenLocal(file:/home/xxx/.m2/repository)
    MavenRepo
```

**UPDATE**

The original settings.gradle.kts is,

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    plugins {
    }
}
plugins {
    id("com.xxx.yyy.zzz.XYZ") version "X.Y.Z"
}

rootProject.name = "svoc-sherlock"

apply(from = "${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle/buildcache.settings.gradle.kts")

include(
    "java-platform",
    "datamodel",
    "lib-common",
    "stream-app-auto-quote-ingestion",
    "stream-app-msiclient-ingestion",
    "stream-app-msianb-quotes-ingestion"
)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `id 'java'` to your plugins block either below or above the `id 'maven-publish'`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp this worked and resolved the error. But in the main project when I am accessing the plugin it is still the same (build error).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

This simply adds the java plugin which is also needed.

**Update**:

In response to your comment:
You need to add this line on your `settings.gradle`:

`rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'` above `include ':app'`.

Comment: kindly have a look into the updated question. I have added the (main) build file.

Comment: So have you tried to add my line i suggested at all? Maybe below the `rootProject.name`?

Comment: Yup. But no change.

Comment: Not an issue. Thanks for your time.